# Как внести значения Restriction и Validation в SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, валидация

Начал писать код для букинг системы в ресторане в Microsoft SQL Server, какие могут быть ограничения в базе данных запросов? Мой код по сслыке:
https://shrib.com/?v=nc#David4goXEpw

- Бронирование не может быть в прошлом времени
- Нельзя забронировать негативное время(17:00-15:00) а только
  позитивное(17:00-19:00)
- Нельзя    бронировать столик на больше чем два часа
- Нельзя бронировать столик в закрытое время ресторана с 22:00-07:00
- Ресторан закрыт в субботу и воскресенье( невозможно забронировать столик в эти дни)
- Количество людей в одном бронировании не может превышать 6-ти человек

Comment: Код нужно перенести в текст вопроса, т.к. ссылка может устареть. И еще не ясно где у вас в таблицах хранится количество человек в бронировании.

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш ответ ниже, он открыл мне глаза!!! Как же приятно видеть результат человека, который разбирается!! Мне код просто скопировать и вставить как текст? Количество человек обозначается partysize, как размер группы

Comment: *Мне код просто скопировать и вставить как текст?* Да. С форматированием, понятное дело. Можно сделать online fiddle и дать ссылку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Большинство ограничений можно реализовать с помощью `CHECK` ограничений.

Выглядеть будет как-то так:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Reservation
(
    reservationID INT not null,
    tableID INT not null,
    creationTime DATETIME DEFAULT GETDATE(),
    startTime DATETIME not null,
    endTime DATETIME not null,
    CONSTRAINT Reservation_end_after_start CHECK (endTime > startTime),
    CONSTRAINT Reservation_not_too_long CHECK (DATEDIFF(mi, startTime, endTime) <= 120),
    CONSTRAINT Reservation_in_future CHECK (creationTime < startTime),
    CONSTRAINT Reservation_in_working_hours CHECK (
             DATEPART(hh, startTime) >= 7 AND DATEPART(hh, startTime) <= 22 
             AND DATEPART(hh, endTime) >= 7 AND DATEPART(hh, endTime) <= 22
    ),
    CONSTRAINT Reservation_on_weekday CHECK (DATEPART(dw, startTime) <= 5), 
)
```

В общем синтаксис такой:

```
  CONSTRAINT <имя-ограничения> CHECK (<выражение которое возвращает true/false>)
```

Т.е. для проверки количества человек в бронировании нужно писать так:

```
CONSTRAINT max_number_visitor CHECK ( partySize<=6 )
```

т.е. выражение должно быть в скобках.

Comment: Могли бы пожалуйста обьяснить значение в 9-ой строке, **(DATEDIFF(mi,?** И если я хочу добавить те дни когда ресторан закрыт, чтобы пользователи не могли резервировать столик в те дни, к примеру, суббота и воскресенье, то я должен добавить WEEKDAY в таблицу Reservation,  и ввести CONSTRAINT для 5, 6?

Comment: offTime WEEKDAY not null, CONSTRAINT Reservation_in_working_hours CHECK (
             DATEPART(hh, startTime) >= 7 AND DATEPART(hh, startTime) <= 22 
             AND DATEPART(hh, endTime) >= 7 AND DATEPART(hh, endTime) <= 22 AND DATEPART(hh, offTime) <= 4 
    ),

Comment: А для ограничения посетителей, CONSTRAINT max_number_visitor CHECK ( partySize) <=6

Comment: `DATEPART` выделяет из даты-времени какую-то часть, это указывается первым аргументом. hh - означает часы, а можно указать `dw` - тогда вернет день недели и не нужно вводить новое поле. Новые поля, которые являются производными от уже существующих не нужно вводить без особой причины. Будет куча проблем с синхронизацией значений в этих полях.

Comment: `DATEDIFF` возвращает разницу между двумя датами, в данном случае в минутах (`mi`).

Comment: Получается просто в моем коментарии заменить hh на dw? Я просто скопировал Ваш код, надеялся так понятнее получится сформулировать, что я вставил туда свой вариант. Только, прошу, не удаляйте эти ЦЕННЫЕ коментарии, а то вдруг эти мелочи вылетят у меня из головы

Comment: Новое поле имеется ввиду "offTime WEEKDAY not null"? Я обычно просто сношу все таблицы DROP и ввожу код по новой, а ни то, я согласен, сразу появляются ошибки

Comment: Правильно ли будет вписан лимит посетителей таким образом? CONSTRAINT max_number_visitor CHECK ( partySize) <=6

Comment: и я имею представление как вписать выходные дгни но не уверен, что это сработает, могу ли я добавить выходные дни в CONSTRAINT Reservation_in_working_hours строку?

Comment: Добавил две новых проверки.

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое!  У меня появился еще один вопрос, почему в строке с рабочим временем мы имеем четыре значения? DATEPART(hh, startTime) >= 7 AND DATEPART(hh, startTime) <= 22 
             AND DATEPART(hh, endTime) >= 7 AND DATEPART(hh, endTime) <= 22

Comment: А где дни недели нам достаточно всего одного?